# Analysis of two audio signal by autocorrelation

Tags: signal-analysis, audio, autocorrelation, audio-processing

I have recorded my audio by two hardware, PC and Microcontroller, I know the PC result are correct but my signal have some deficit. I have recorded by my PC and MCU my voice 6s 7812Hz and autocorrelation of each one become :
[image: xcorr]
Auto in case excitation being white noise:
[image: XCORRwhite]
It seems in MCU we have summed with triangle signal in comparison with the PC signal autocorrelation.

Crosscorrelation :

[image: cross]

White noise excitation cross-correlation (note both signal are recorded from one noise with small delay(PC have delay)):

[image: crossWhite]

I know what autocorrelation function is. Why mcu auto-corr has summed with triangle? Also two signal must be at some point highly correlated but its weird! what can be inferred?

### Update

Why cross correlation of white noises is not spike? Also note the end of cross being zero, it have zero tail, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "MCU" plot looks like there was a DC component in the signal, that ran through the autocorrelation function. The triangle is typical for this. Try highpass filtering before the analysis.

Regarding your second question: the plot looks quite normal for autocorrelation of a speech signal. There are always tonal/peridodic components in speech, which is why sometimes the maxium of the autocorrelation function isn't quite clear. In fact, this plot looks like there could be a repetition of the same word or syllable in the speech material.

EDIT:

The small plots of whitenoise autocorrelation are looking good, one clear peak, as can be expected.

The big plot seems to be the *cross*correlation (it also says so in the text) of two different white noise signals. There can't be any peak, as the signals are in no way correlated.

Comment: How you've understand there is a repetition of syllable or word? because cross correlation is broadband?

Comment: The three very distinct peaks are telltale for a repetition of some kind.

Comment: Thank you so much. yes I'm using GNU octave xcorr function.

Comment: Could you please  watching the question again since I've updated it with white noise data.

Comment: I've made an edit to the answer.

Comment: Those are recorded the same time from white noise, then cross have to peak, otherwise have to be near zero. But as you see cross have a zero tail.

Comment: Were they recorded with the exact same equipment at the exact same point in time?

Comment: just the equipment are different, My problem got solve though the diagrams must be normal. the signal dc however appears in triangular auto correlation, thanks so much.